# Touch UI v/s Classic UI in AEM

Tags: aem

How do we check whether the html page in Adobe Experience Manager/CQ5 is opened in touch mode or classic mode?

Comment: You want to check this in Sightly ?

Comment: sightly will do. Or any other method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add dependency to `/libs/wcm/foundation/components/utils/AuthoringUtils.js` and then call `AuthoringUtils.isTouch` and `AuthoringUtils.isClassic` to check whether it is currently in touch or the classic mode. For e.g., your JS Use API would look something like below.

```
"use strict";

use(["/libs/wcm/foundation/components/utils/AuthoringUtils.js"], function (AuthoringUtils) {
    if (AuthoringUtils.isTouch) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }

    // rest of the things
}
```

Comment: Kindly consider accepting the answer in case it was helpful